# How can a static variable (global variable) be an object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, static, instance, public

Ok, off the bat, I know this question either sounds like common sense, or very confusing due to its wording. Unfortunately, due to my lack of knowledge even after much research, I am unsure how to phrase it. To my understanding at this point, static variables do not refer to an instance of a class, and a class.method call is used to access them. variables declared non-static and public are instances of the class and can be called using an object.method call. However, in recent examples, I have seen statements such as:

```
private static Rectangle rect;
```

why not just write

```
public Rectangle rect;
```

How is this possible? I thought that static variables were *not associated with instances of classes*? **I am just very confused regarding the meaning and limitations/usages of static versus non-static.** I apologize for any confusion. If this question deems unanswerable, a link providing an example of SIMPLE differentiation between static and public usage would be greatly appreciated. I am a complete beginner so please avoid using too much technical jargon.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public/protected/private` have nothing to do with `static`.

`static` means a member (be it a data member or a method) belongs to the **class**, and not to a specific **instance**.

`public/protected/private` just control what other classes can access these members, be it instance members or `static` members.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I realized this immediately after I posted the question and edited it. So what would the difference be between non-static and static? Could you refer to easy to understand examples? Thank you @Mureinik and anyone else willing to help me :)

Comment: Non-static means instance variable.  It belongs to each object. [(Link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` below:

```
public class FirstClass {
    private static Rectangle rect;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class SecondClass {
    private Rectangle rect; 
    // getters and setters
}
```

You can create as many instances of `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` as you like. However, the `rect` is treated differently by the two classes due to the `static` keyword:

- In case of `FirstClass`, `rect` is a **class variable**, mening that there will only be a single reference to an instance of `Rectangle`. Note, that depending on the implementation of `FirstClass` you may or may not have to instantiate `FirstClass` at all, and yet there is a reference to the `rect`.
- In case of `SecondClass`, `rect` is an instance variable meaning that each instance of `SecondClass` will always have a reference to an instance of a `Rectangle`. However, these references do not exist unless `SecondClass` is instantiated.

I suggest that you read up on [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in the official Java tutorial. From the very first line:

> the `static` keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the difference, consider this example:

```
class MyClass {
    public static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    public Rectangle rect1;
    public MyClass(Rectangle rect1) {
       this.rect1 = rect1
    }
}
```

Now if i do like:

```
MyClass clazz1 = new MyClass(new Rectangle());
MyClass clazz2 = new MyClass(new Rectangle());
```

How many instance you see of rect and how many rect1? You could have rect1 associated with each and every object while you will have just one instance of rect and being shared by every class.

Comment: isn't that a bit confusing, shared by every class means every class in every file can access this variable(even if the class was a package class), shared by every object means every object of this class can access that variable.

Answer (score 0):

First to undestand difference , assume this like written in some class Foo,

```
public class Foo{
  private static Rectangle rect;
}
```

It means rect is member of Foo class , which being private cannot be access from some other class. And being static, you don't need to create object and will be share across all the instances of Foo.

```
public class Foo{
 public  Rectangle rect;
}
```

It means rect can be accessed from any other class by creating instance of Foo.

When we static is not associate with any object , it means you need not to create object for accessin static variable and its shared amoung all the the instances.
However, private/public/proctected is related to visibility from other classes.